# How to get the object value based on a certain condition in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am playing with JS objects. And I came across a challenging situation for me:

basically I have a JS object:

```
let cinfo = {
   "costing_T063623477Z":{
      "service":[
         {
            "objid":"T063637283Z",
            "serviceid":"SRV2100003",
            "servicename":"FABRICATION OF SPRINKLER & HOSE",
            "estimatedprice":"10000.00",
            "description":"sdfg",
            "laborcost":"500.00"
         }
      ],
      "othercharges":[
         {
            "objid":"T063911531Z",
            "description":"Other Expenses",
            "amount":"345.00",
            "remarks":"345"
         },
         {
            "objid":"T063906963Z",
            "description":"Sales Expenses",
            "amount":"345.00",
            "remarks":"345"
         },
         {
            "objid":"T063730836Z",
            "description":"Delivery Expenses",
            "amount":"345.00",
            "remarks":"345"
         },
         {
            "objid":"T063730836Z",
            "description":"Delivery Expenses",
            "amount":"345.00",
            "remarks":"345"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I have something that can get the values of a specific object:

```
Object.keys(cinfo).forEach(function(ckey) {
     cinfo[ckey].service.forEach(function(skey){
         console.log(skey.laborcost);
     })
})
```

Based on the object above, the console output is: `500.00`

But, I want something conditional when it comes to `othercharges` object.
I need to get the amount based only on the description:

Something like this:

```
Object.keys(cinfo).forEach(function(ckey) {
     cinfo[ckey].othercharges.forEach(function(skey){
          console.log(skey.amount) //-> where "description" = "Other Expenses";
          console.log(skey.amount) //-> where "description" = "Sales Expenses";
          console.log(skey.amount) //-> where "description" = "Delivery Expenses";
     })
}
```

How to make it possible? Thanks.

Comment: You should stop playing with [JSON objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON), and start to play with JS objects.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```js
let cinfo = {
   "costing_T063623477Z":{
      "service":[
         {
            "objid":"T063637283Z",
            "serviceid":"SRV2100003",
            "servicename":"FABRICATION OF SPRINKLER & HOSE",
            "estimatedprice":"10000.00",
            "description":"sdfg",
            "laborcost":"500.00"
         }
      ],
      "othercharges":[
         {
            "objid":"T063911531Z",
            "description":"Other Expenses",
            "amount":"345.00",
            "remarks":"345"
         },
         {
            "objid":"T063906963Z",
            "description":"Sales Expenses",
            "amount":"345.00",
            "remarks":"345"
         },
         {
            "objid":"T063730836Z",
            "description":"Delivery Expenses",
            "amount":"345.00",
            "remarks":"345"
         },
         {
            "objid":"T063730836Z",
            "description":"Delivery Expenses",
            "amount":"100.00",
            "remarks":"345"
         }
      ]
   }
}

const getServiceCharge = (info) => {
  const key = Object.keys(info)[0]; // Get first key in object
  return info[key].service[0].laborcost;
}

const getOtherCharge = (info, desc) => {
  const key = Object.keys(info)[0]; // Get first key in object
  const otherCharges = info[key].othercharges;
  
  const sumAmount = otherCharges
    .filter(item => item.description === desc) // Get only items we are looking for
    .reduce((sum, item) => sum + Number(item.amount), 0); // Sum amount 

  return sumAmount;    
}

console.log(`Service Labor charge: ${getServiceCharge(cinfo)}`);
console.log(`Service Other Expenses charge: ${getOtherCharge(cinfo, "Other Expenses")}`);
console.log(`Service Sales Expenses charge: ${getOtherCharge(cinfo, "Sales Expenses")}`);
console.log(`Service Delivery Expenses charge: ${getOtherCharge(cinfo, "Delivery Expenses")}`);
```

Comment: what if there are multiple "Delivery Expenses" ? I updated my question

Comment: and how do you want the answer, sum value of all "Delivery Expresses"?

Comment: Yes, it should add all with the same description.

Answer (score 1):

```js
Object.keys(cinfo).forEach(function(ckey) {
     // Get only 1 other charges
     // Return object
     const deliveryExpenses = cinfo[key].othercharges.find(item => item.description == "Delivery Expenses")
     // Get all other charges base on the comparison
     // Returns array
     const deliveryExpenses = cinfo[key].othercharges.filter(item => item.description == "Delivery Expenses")

}
```

Heres the docs in using find.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: Wow. this works great!

Comment: what if there are multiple "Delivery Expenses" ?

Comment: It will only get the first one to appear,
If you want to get all those `Delivery Expenses` you have to use filter instead

Comment: I use filter and it returns "undefined"

Comment: Thats weird, can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

```js
let cinfo = {
  costing_T063623477Z: {
    service: [
      {
        objid: "T063637283Z",
        serviceid: "SRV2100003",
        servicename: "FABRICATION OF SPRINKLER & HOSE",
        estimatedprice: "10000.00",
        description: "sdfg",
        laborcost: "500.00"
      }
    ],
    othercharges: [
      {
        objid: "T063911531Z",
        description: "Other Expenses",
        amount: "345.00",
        remarks: "345"
      },
      {
        objid: "T063906963Z",
        description: "Sales Expenses",
        amount: "345.00",
        remarks: "345"
      },
      {
        objid: "T063730836Z",
        description: "Delivery Expenses",
        amount: "345.00",
        remarks: "345"
      }
    ]
  }
};

function getCharge(serviceCharge = null, otherCharges = null) {
  if (serviceCharge) {
    return cinfo.costing_T063623477Z.service[0].laborcost;
  }
  return cinfo.costing_T063623477Z.othercharges.filter(
    (t) => t.description === otherCharges
  ).map(t=>t.amount);
}

console.log(getCharge(true));
console.log(getCharge(null, "Other Expenses"));
console.log(getCharge(null, "Sales Expenses"));
console.log(getCharge(null, "Delivery Expenses"));
```

Lets do it in a more smart way. I hope It will work.

Comment: what if there are multiple "Delivery Expenses" ? I updated my question

Comment: Dear @jreloz I just edit the answer. You have to use the filter method in case of multiple objects.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer, using only one loop (through `.reduce`), and setting every thing up just by assigning some variables in the right places.

It works with multiple `services` or if multiple `descriptions` share the same value.

```js
let cinfo = {
   "costing_T063623477Z":{
      "service":[
         {
            "objid":"T063637283Z",
            "serviceid":"SRV2100003",
            "servicename":"FABRICATION OF SPRINKLER & HOSE",
            "estimatedprice":"10000.00",
            "description":"sdfg",
            "laborcost":"500.00"
         }
      ],
      "othercharges":[
         {
            "objid":"T063911531Z",
            "description":"Other Expenses",
            "amount":"345.00",
            "remarks":"345"
         },
         {
            "objid":"T063906963Z",
            "description":"Sales Expenses",
            "amount":"345.00",
            "remarks":"345"
         },
         {
            "objid":"T063730836Z",
            "description":"Delivery Expenses",
            "amount":"345.00",
            "remarks":"345"
         },
         {
            "objid":"T063730836Z",
            "description":"Delivery Expenses",
            "amount":"100.00",
            "remarks":"345"
         }
      ]
   }
}

function getCost(obj, othercharges) {
  let key = Object.keys(obj)[0],
      subKey =   (othercharges) ? 'othercharges' : 'service',
      property = (othercharges) ? 'amount'       : 'laborcost',
      childObj = obj[key][subKey];
  
  return childObj.reduce((totalSum, item) => {
    let itemSum = 0;
    
    if (!othercharges || item.description == othercharges) {
      itemSum = item[property];
    }

    return totalSum + Number(itemSum);
  }, 0);
}

console.log( getCost(cinfo) ); // returns 'laborcost'
console.log( getCost(cinfo, 'Delivery Expenses') );
```